# Connect backend with database in docker

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

I have simple `phpmyadmin`, `mysql` containers.

I create new folder with `backend` in `nodejs`. At now, I just can't connect to `database` through `backend`.

All three containers (`phpmyadmin`, `mysql`, `api`) works and launch. But container api don't connect with database.

This is my main `db.js` file for connection, which is always throw error.

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "db_user",
    password: "db_user_pass",
    database: "any-game",
    port: 8899,
});

db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong!"); //  Get error always in this line because can't connect to db
    }
});

module.exports = db;
```

Url for `phpmyadmin` is `localhost:8899`. Phpmyadmin work as I expect. Without any error. I can log in to db through login and password in docker-compose. But can't connect with backend.

And `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: "3"

services:
  phpmyadmin: 
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin1
    environment: 
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=db
      - PMA_PORT=3306
    restart: always
    links:
      - db
    ports: 
      - 8899:80
    depends_on:
      - db

  api:
    build: ./api
    container_name: api1
    command: npm run start
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3005:3005"
    environment: 
      - PORT=3005
    depends_on:
      - phpmyadmin

  db: 
    image: mysql
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_secret_password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=guess-game
      - MYSQL_USER=db_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=db_user_pass
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 6033:3306
```

I tried to write like this:

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "db_user",
    password: "db_user_pass",
    database: "any-game",
});
```

Like this

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "db_user",
    password: "db_user_pass",
    database: "any-game",
    port: 80,
});
```

Or

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "db_user",
    password: "db_user_pass",
    database: "any-game",
    port: 6033, // DB port
});
```

Even

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "db_user",
    password: "db_user_pass",
    database: "any-game",
});
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with docker containers, to communicate with different containers, you can do in following ways

1. Establish connection using hostname
2. Establish connection using proxy and sidecar to make use of localhost.

In your case try following snippet,

```js
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "db",
    user: "db_user",
    password: "db_user_pass",
    database: "any-game",
    port: 3306,
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not working 

Comment: Check for port number in db configuration