# Connection problem with flask-sqlalchemy and Docker database

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a problem with my connection between my flask app using flask-sqlalchemy and my database container, i want to make a compose project.
I'm currently using Python3 Flask and MySQL as my database, im trying to connect both containers into a network but i just cant them to get connect.
Need to add that if i run my code locally, just using my editor it works perfectly connecting to my db container, the problem is when i want to create and use my project container.

This is my URI:
`app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'mysql+mysqlconnector://{db_user}:{db_psw}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_schema}?connect_timeout=60'`

Here are my env vars, i already have loaded them with dotenv:

```
database_host = 'db'
database_port = 3308
database_user = 'root'
database_psw = 'toor'
database_schema = 'db_news'
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_news
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - default

  app:
    container_name: app
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:4000"
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    networks:
      - default

volumes:
  database_data:

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

And finally my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

COPY .env .env

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["python3", "app/app.py"]
```

I have tried changing the port, using 'localhost' as host but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you try to remove the networks section from the yaml and let docker compose create the network for you?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, what do i need to erase from my Dockerfile? All the network stuff code?

Comment: I'd suggest deleting all of the `networks:` blocks, the `container_name:` overrides, and the obsolete `links:` setting; none of these are necessary.  The `volumes:` mounting something over `/app` seems likely to overwrite all of the code built into the image, which can result in some hard-to-debug issues, and I might also delete that.

Comment: I deleted all of what you recommend but still didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please confirm if this is correct?

```ini
database_host = 'db'
database_port = 3306 # not 3308
database_user = 'root'
database_psw = 'toor'
database_schema = 'db_news'
```

=====================================

## Rebuild Image

```bash
docker compose rm # remove container
docker compose build # rebuild image
docker compose up
```

Comment: By the way, you can import the `.env` file on top of the `docker-compose.yml` file instead of using it in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Im little confuse with that, now you saying it, im sort of new with Docker, do i need to use in all my config files the port 3306 when using a database container? 

And how can i import .env file on my compose file? Thanks for answer

Comment: Connections between containers don't consider or require `ports:`; they always use the standard port number for the service, which for MySQL is 3306.

Comment: Yes. You need to change your configuration file to connect to MySQL as `db:3306`

Comment: If you use `env-file` in your `docker-compose.yml`, you won't need to rebuild.
`ref:`https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#use-the-env_file-attribute

Comment: The thing is that my port 3306 is currently in using so i tried to mapping to 3308 and tried to use 3308 instead of 3306

Comment: So all i have to do is: 

```
app:
    env_file:
      - .env
```
 

instead of copying it on my Dockerfile, right?

Comment: Can you close Port `3306`?

Comment: You can also change the `ports` to `expose: - 3306`.

Comment: I want to use `3308` because i'll share my containers with some people, and maybe they have the `port 3306` using

Comment: But i can run it and it works perfectly in locally, cant figure out whats the problem between containers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70914739/connect-backend-with-database-in-docker

Comment: In the article I provided, the author's database is configured as `6033` externally, but within the same Docker network it is still `3306`.

Comment: can you provide the updated `docker-compose.yaml` and also what error is shown?
And did you check that your mysql container is running?

Comment: It worked, using the port `3306` and cleaning a little my `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Ok, Congratulations  choose best answer 

Comment: Really thanks @chunyen and all who helped me!

Answer (score 0):

My `docker-compose.yml` updated

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_news
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/mysql

  app:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: app
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:4000"
 
volumes:
  database_data:
```